# What's the use of allowing to copy empty string to clipboard?

Tags: interaction-design, text-editor, copy-paste

Typical applications that allow copying text to clipboard only enable "Copy" action when there's some nonempty chunk of text selected, otherwise Ctrl-C has no effect. Not so with MS Visual Studio editor - you can put the caret anywhere in the text and press Ctrl-C and you have an empty string copied into the clipboard (and the previous content in the clipboard is erased as usual).

This is a bit of annoying when you press Ctrl-C instead of Ctrl-V because you get the clipboard contents lost instead of pasted at the caret position.

Is there any use in such behavior?

Comment: Sounds most definitely like a bug. Forward it to Microsoft support instead.

Comment: @AndroidHustle: I've seen it filed in MS Connect may years ago. It is not fixed yet, so maybe there's some use in this behavior.

Comment: if copying an empty String and thereby, as you've also experienced, unintentionally erase any actual content on the clipboard is part of a feature I'd sure be curious to hear about it! :)

Comment: @AndroidHustle: I'm curious too, so I asked this question.

Comment: Do you mean it copies an empty string when you're on an empty line? It will copy the line if you press Ctrl+C without a selection but you can disable that option I believe.

Comment: You can disable this behavior: From the menu, select Tools | Options | Text Editor | All Languages

Then deselect the checkbox beside Apply Cut or Copy Commands to blank lines when there is no selection

Comment: Additionally, your question implies that you aren't familiar with the clipboard ring.  Press ctrl + shift + v to cycle through the last 15 things you have added to the clipboard, so even if you accidentally copy a blank line, your previous item is still in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is no use for pasting an empty string, so the only potential use would be to **clear the contents of the clipboard**.  A programmer might have been copying and pasting very specific lines of code and want to clear his or her clipboard to ensure that those lines weren't pasted anything else.  I personally wouldn't use the feature, but I could imagine someone wanting it to help reduce security vulnerabilities on a shared computer.

I agree that this breaks the user's mental model of how copy and paste should work, though, so I suggest against implementing this "feature" in any future products that interact with the user's clipboard.

Comment: *Clear clipboard* is indeed not much needed, and if it was, you could still select a single space character and copy that to clipboard. Things are different for clipboards, which allow you to copy multiple contents and paste them individually (FIFO, LIFO or arbitrary order), a button or menu option to clear everything would be useful. Some code editors offer a second shortcut for pasting, to swap the selected text with the clipboard content, and a second paste pastes what was selected for pasting the first time. Not not sure if you would want a clear function in this case, or just paste twice.